# How to create legends with matplotlib in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, legend

I'm creating a graph with matplotlib in Python using a loop. The loop go trough a dictionary  **dict_df** containing several data frames (keys are **df1**, df2,...). The number of data frames, and therefore the number of legends, is not fixed. Each data frame is really simple: they contain 2 columns, and all data frame must be plotted in the same graph:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.grid(True)

m = 1
while m < i:
    plt.plot((dict_df[str("df")+str(m)])["Turns Adjusted"],(dict_df[str("df")+str(m)])["Torque Adjusted"])
    m = m + 1

plt.show()
```

The plot shows the the graph correctly, but I don't know how to add legends or label for each data frame, using the same loop.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Pass `label="label"` to the `plt.plot` function and then call `plt.legend()` outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks @MustafaAydın it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the argument `label='...'` to your calls of `plt.plot`, and add `plt.legend()` in the end after the loop and before `plt.show()`.